# How can I pass data from ArrayList<String> to List<Class?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I want to save/parse data from ArrayList to List but I'm not able to figure out how can I achieve it.

I have 2 Lists as below:

```
public static ArrayList<String> list2= new ArrayList<>();
public static List<Contact> sortedList= new ArrayList<>();
```

list2 is having data like

```
ArrayList<String> list2 = ["9847523587", "6738654738"]
```

I want list2 data in sortedList.
How can I get that?

Contact.java

```
public class Contact implements Serializable, Comparable<Contact> {
/**
 *
 */

private String fullName, firstName, lastName, androidId, androidRawId, androidTagId, organization;
private transient Uri photoUri, thumbnailUri;
private List<NumberOrAddress> addresses;
private transient ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> changesToCommit;
private transient ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> changesToCommit2;

public void setInitial(String initial) {
    this.initial = initial;
}

public Contact() {
    addresses = new ArrayList<>();
    androidId = null;
    thumbnailUri = null;
    photoUri = null;
    changesToCommit = new ArrayList<>();

    changesToCommit2 = new ArrayList<>();
    hasSipAddress = false;
}
}
}
```

Added Contact.java just to show how its constructed.

Comment: What is the purpose of `list1`?

Comment: Can you share the Contact class?

Comment: No purpose of list1 in this question, sorry for not informing.

Comment: @Developer Please edit your question and remove list1.

Comment: Edited, please provide a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You need some method which takes a `String` and returns a `Contact` in order to convert between the two different types.

If `Contact` has a constructor which takes a string, for example, then you can do:

```
list2.stream()
    .map(Contact::new)
    .forEach(sortedList::add);
```

Comment: Getting :
Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert org.Contact to R
and 
cannot resolve method 'add'

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this(assuming `contact.getContactString()` returns the required string):

```
for(Contact contact: list1){
    list2.add(contact.getContactString());
}

Collection.sort(list2);
```

And then:

```
  for(String str: list2){
    // assuming Contact can be constructed using a String
    sortedList.add(new Contact(str)); 
 }
```

Comment: @ModusTollens My bad. Changed the answer.

Comment: @ModusTollens Oh. What is list1 doing then in the question?

Comment: I am confused as well. It:s not needed.

Comment: Yes, it's not needed.
Sorry for adding it.

Comment: @Developer Changed my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: It might work but my Contact does not have string as a constructor.
I've added the Contact class above.

Comment: How can i add a string constructor so that it works?

Comment: @PritamBanerjee

Comment: @Developer Then add one comparable. Google up how to sort objects using comparators. That would help